# I didn't understand some CSS rules in bootstrap file

Tags: css

I saw in bootstrap css file, there's some rules like

```
*margin-left: 8.404255319148938%;
```

and

```
*zoom:1;
```

I don't understand why the `*`, is there any one who can explain this CSS trick?

Comment: That's ok, neither do most browsers ;)  That's the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular trick is to target Internet Explorer. It is more clearly explained here http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/

Comment: also u should know it causes your css file doesnt verify by W3C, if u dont wanna support below IE 8 drop it

Comment: this is correct.  I guess with the advent of IE8 and 9, slowly these hacks will start to fade away.  Remember the holly hack for ie6? that was for me one hack that never made sense and caused more issues down the line for other browsers.

Comment: I prefer using conditional comments to add an IE class to the `<html>` tag to deal with old versions of IE, like HTML5 Boilerplate suggests. Obviously with CSS that’s meant to be dropped in anywhere independently, like Twitter Bootstrap, that approach doesn’t work.

Comment: you can also use tools like modernizr.  these will add an ie8 or ie7 tag to your body so you can target a specific browser without having to rely on * so for example you can do .ie7 .offendingElement{ ... }

Comment: Think you very much, any way I wanted just to know because it didn't make sense for me, I will remove them as IE7+ support all rules without that *